# Javascript RegExp: Searching for everything wrapped with a spezific char or string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, markdown, showdown

I am writing a blog and use markdown language for the entered content to render. Now I try to filter everything outside of code-blocks (marked with triple back-ticks) for HTML-Tags and want to replace them.
However, my current RegExp Pattern isn't working properly, and considering, that I am new to RegExp, i can't find my issue, here is the Pattern I use:

````
/```(.*)```/g
````

This works just fine, If I want to strip apart every match, but when I want to split the text, according to this pattern, JavaScript is just looking for the triple back-ticks and not the whole Pattern.

**EDIT:**

Here is my code where I use the pattern to split the text i get from a textfield:

````js
function preformatInput(text){
    let noCode = text.split(/```(.*)```/g);
    let indizes = [];
    let length = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<noCode.length; i++){
        // indizes.push(text.find(i));
        if(i>0)indizes.push(text.indexOf(noCode[i], text.indexOf(noCode[i-1])));
        else indizes.push(text.indexOf(noCode[i]));

        length.push(noCode[i].length);
    }
    for(let i = 0; i<noCode.length; i++){
        noCode[i] = stripHTML(noCode[i]);
    }
    console.log(indizes);
    console.log(length);
}
````

Comment: Where's the code that shows your actual code using the regex and what input you're passing it?

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for the response, I added my code where I use the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```` /```[^```]+```/g ```` does not work, the expression works the same way as ```` /```[^`]+```/g ```` and forbids single/double `` '`' ``s.

Use

````js
/```[\s\S]*?```/g
````

**EXPLANATION**

````js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```                      '```'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all but \n,
                           \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```                      '```'
````

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the Problem:**
I changed my RegExp Pattern to the following: ```` /```[^```]+```/g ```` and it worked.